# ASP.NET Core Web API - Moving the appsettettings.json file breaks my application

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, .net-5

I want to move the `appsettings.json` file inside the `app` folder, but when I do that the object `Configuration` in the startup class cannot access to connection string.

[image]

If I leave the `appsettings.json` file in the root as it comes by default, everything works correctly. Does anyone know what it is due to and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set the app's configuration by calling `ConfigureAppConfiguration` when building the host, like below.

```
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
{
    config.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "app", "appsettings.json"),
                        optional: false, reloadOnChange: false);
})
```

For more information about configuring the JSON configuration provider to load the specific json settings file, please check this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#json-configuration-provider